# How do I replace "/" with "\" in r?

Tags: r

I am trying do that "C:/Users/Vitor/Documents" become "C:\Users\Vitor\Documents".

I tried :

```
gsub("//", "\", file)
paste(dirname(file),basename(file),sep="\")
normalizePath(file,"\",mustWork=FALSE)
```

But didn't work!

Comment: Try `gsub("/", "\\\\", "C:/Users/Vitor/Documents")`

Comment: stay that way "C:\\Users\\Vitor\\Documents"

Comment: Try with `cat(gsub("/", "\\\\", "C:/Users/Vitor/Documents"))#`, or get the `nchar(gsub("/", "\\\\", "C:/Users/Vitor/Documents"))` it is a single character

Comment: The function cat works but i'm want get the output, by the way a <- cat(gsub("/", "\\\\", "C:/Users/Vitor/Documents")) .

Comment: `cat` only prints.  You can just use the `gsub` output.  If you want to write it in a `file`. then `cat(gsub("/", "\\\\", "C:/Users/Vitor/Documents"), file = "file1.txt")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can escape the `\` with another set and use it in `gsub` as the `\\` is just one character

```
gsub("/", "\\\\", "C:/Users/Vitor/Documents")
```

which would print correctly with `cat`

```
cat(gsub("/", "\\\\", "C:/Users/Vitor/Documents"))
#C:\Users\Vitor\Documents
```

and can check the number of characters

```
nchar("\\")
#[1] 1
```